# Batch inserts with JPA/EJB3

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, batch-insert

Does JPA/EJB3 framework provide standard way to do batch insert operation...?
We use hibernate for persistence framework, So I can fall back to Hibernate Session and use combination session.save()/session.flush() achieve batch insert. But would like to know if EJB3 have a support for this...

Answer (score 23):

Neither JPA nor Hibernate do provide particular support for batch inserts and the idiom for batch inserts with JPA would be the same as with Hibernate:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    em.persist(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Using Hibernate's proprietary API in this case doesn't provide any advantage IMO.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 4.10 "Bulk Update and Delete Operations"
- Hibernate Core reference guide

  - [Chapter 13. Batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)

Comment: Just for sanity check, your `if` statement should be `i > 0 && i % 20 == 0` else it'll flush (and clear) immediately after the first element was added.

Answer (score 6):

With medium records number you can use this way:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
     Point point = new Point(i, i);
     em.persist(point);
     if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
          em.flush();
          em.clear();
     }
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

But with large records number you should perform this task in multiple transactions:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
      Point point = new Point(i, i);
      em.persist(point);
      if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
          em.getTransaction().commit();
          em.clear();          
          em.getTransaction().begin();
      }
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Ref: [JPA Batch Store](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/store#Batch_Store_)

Answer (score 5):

For hibernate specifically, the whole [chapter 13 of the core manual](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/batch.html) explain the methods.

But you are saying that you want the EJB method through Hibernate, so the entity manager documentation also has a chapter on that [here](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#batch). I suggest that you read both (the core and the entity manager).

In EJB, it is simply about using EJB-QL (with some limitations). Hibernate provides more mechanics though if you need more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can rollback to your JPA implementation if you wish in order to have the control you defined.

JPA 1.0 is rich on EL-HQL but light on Criteria API support, however this has been addressed in 2.0.

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pascal

In your example to insert 100000 records, it is done within single transaction, as the commit() is only called at the end.. Does it put a lot pressure towards the database? Furthermore, in case there is rollback, the cost will be too much..

Will the following approach be better?

```
EntityManager em = ...;
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
   if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
   }
   Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
   em.persist(customer);
   if ((i+1) % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
      //flush and commit of inserts and release memory:
      em.getTransaction().commit(); 
      em.clear();
   }
}

session.close();
```