# Why JPA/Hibernate is not performing batching?

Tags: jpa-2.0

My Entity class looks as follows :

```
@Entity
class Entity {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;


    // normal getters and setters

    @PrePersist
    public void init(){
        if(id == null){
            setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        }
    }
```

In my persistence.xml, I have following :-

```
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
```

Within a single transaction,
I am calling "entityManager.persist(myEntity)" inside a for loop. The exact number of iterations may vary across multiple runs.

In my logging configuration I have following,

```
<logger category="org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

However, in the server's log, I can not find any evidence of any sort of batching being performed during insert.
I am using Hibernate as a JPA provider.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Isn't batching works for select only?

Comment: Yeah, I also think that batching is only for reading collections of entities and similar stuff.

Comment: Look at this link, it does support batch inserts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448181/batch-inserts-with-jpa-ejb3