# Persist list of Entities with <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-integration

I may be missing something here but I cannot seem to find any docs about persisting a List of Entities using Spring Integration JPA Outbound Channel Adapter. I have an extremely simple scenario that should poll a database and copy new data across to another database. Thus:

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myChannel"
    entity-class="my.package.MyClass"
    entity-manager="mysqlEntityManager"
    auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" transaction-manager="mysqlTransactionManager"/>
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="myChannel" />

<int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter channel="myChannel" 
    entity-class="my.package.MyClass"
    entity-manager="hsqldbEntityManager">
    <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="hsqldbTransactionManager" />                                    
</int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

The `inbound-channel-adapter` returns a `List<MyClass>` and then the `outbound-channel-adapter` throws the stack trace below...

How do I configure the adapter to accept a list of entites? I do not want to set max messages per poll in the inbound adapter/poller, as I would prefer minimal database operations.

Any help appreciated.

Spring docs:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.M1/reference/html/jpa.html

```
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGateway@165d2be]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy24.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:82)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy23.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:692)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy18.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.merge(DefaultJpaOperations.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.JpaExecutor.executeOutboundJpaOperation(JpaExecutor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JpaOutboundGateway.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1485)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686)
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outbound JPA adapter doesn't currently support persisting a list of entities; feel free to open a new [JIRA Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT). You can add a simple `<splitter/>` before the outbound adapter (no attributes, just input and output channels) and it will bust the list into individual entitities.

However, with your current configuration, each persist will be done in a separate transaction.

Regardless, you probably want to synchronize the two transactions anyway so you should really  start the hsql transaction at the same time as the mysql transaction so that Spring will make best efforts to synchronize the two transactions (commit them as close together as possible).

To do that, you'd need something like the ChainedTransactionManager in the ['Best Efforts 1PC' section of Dave Syer's excellent article on this subject](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html).

This way, each of the split entities will be committed in the same transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I need to do more reading on transactions and transaction managers! For now I have just directed the List to a POJO and persisted manually... I will open a ticket if I get time. Sorry can't up-vote your answer as I don't have enough rep :(

Answer (score 4):

I have created a Jira in order to make that improvement:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-3029

As a work-around you could also extend **DefaultJpaOperations** (org.springframework.integration.jpa.core) and customize the *persist()* method, allowing you to handle a Collection type parameters. For some details see:

[Batch inserts with JPA/EJB3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448181/batch-inserts-with-jpa-ejb3)

The adapters have an XML namespace attribute **jpa-operations**, allowing you to provide a reference to custom implementations. For more details, please see http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jpa.html#jpa-namespace-support-common-attributes